# Updating LuaTeX version in MiKTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex

I have MiKTeX 2.9, which comes packaged with LuaTeX version beta-0.70.2-2012060719. I'd like to compile a file using the [latest stable version](https://foundry.supelec.fr/frs/?group_id=10&release_id=406). I've downloaded the binary, but what do I do with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX !. No idea, but may be a [feature request like this to author](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/feature-requests/292/) or [with TeXLive 2013, it's  beta-0.76.0-2013061708](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried running the "Update MikTeX" utility? It should give you an option to update lots of packages as well as pretty much the entire LuaTeX subsystem. (There are many packages that go with Lua(La)Tex, e.g., `luaotfload`. Be sure to update those packages as well, not just the binary.)

Comment: I would run the Update from the Maintenance menu. This grabs all possible updates from a repository of your choice and places them in the right folder. One thing: Be careful with updating when you actually work with LaTeX as dependecies between packets can change and render your files not working.

Comment: @Chris and Mico (SX won't let me tag both of you), what should I choose as my source? By default it has my local package repository selected (C:\proTeXt\MiKTeX\tm\packages).

Comment: @skiasaurus - Selecting the local package repository won't do you any good unless it's up up-to-date anyway. (Do you know how maintains your local repository?) I'd choose the button that says "I want to get updated packages from a remote package repository"; the one's that "nearest to you" will probably do fine.

Comment: You have to check the point "I want to get updated packages from a remote package repository:" and then choose either the nearest repository a choose one by hand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with an update of MiKTeX.